# Window 2008 inherit permissions from parent on file created on linux nfs share connected to Windows

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, permissions, nfs

I have a Windows 2008 server with a NFS share called myhost/host_dev. The windows NFS share is set up to allow 'unmapped user access'. I am able to mount a Linux directory to that share using mount -t nfs myhost:/host_dev. If I create files on Linux they show up in Windows and vise versa as they should.

The problem is that the files created on the Linux side don't inherit the permissions of the parent NFS shared directory on Windows. So only 'System','Administrators',and the created 'SIDs' so up as having permissions to the file. I want the files to inherit the 'Everyone' group as well so that everyone has read access. Right now, because the 'Everyone' permissions aren't being inherited I get access denied when trying to open the file.

Comment: I am here from the future to inform you that this remains a problem on Server 2019 and information on it is still sparse.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer! It's frustrating that Microsoft leaves this bit of information out of ALL their documentation, including the official NFS_Account_Mapping documentation found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14205).

The answer is in the registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Server for NFS\CurrentVersion\Mapping\KeepInheritance

Change the value to a 1 and restart NFS.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sfu/archive/2009/08/28/how-nfs-access-works-over-ntfs-permissions.aspx

Comment: Update to the technet blog... the URL changed.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/technet/sfu/how-nfs-access-works-over-ntfs-permissions