# Access rights are not inherited for new files

Tags: nfs, windows-server-2022

I am trying to provide an NFS share on a Windows Server 2022. This share is mounted by different Linux/Solaris systems.

The plan is to keep everything simple in the first place. The share should enable full access rights, which can then be restricted afterwards by IP access rights.

In the test, folders and files that were created by the server/Win could generally be used without any problems. Any access and editing is possible.

However, if the files or folders were created by an NFS client then the Unix privileges of the client user appear to be applied. The inheritance structure of the underlying NTFS file system is not taken into account. This means that no direct access to the new files or folders is possible under Windows. You have to take ownership every single time and redefine the access rights.

The NFS Share Service was successfully installed and set up with the following settings:

```
Kerberos v5 privacy: OFF
Kerberos v5 integrity: OFF
Kerberos v5 authentication: OFF
No server authentication: ON
Enable unmapped user access: ON
Allow unmapped user Unix access (by UID/GID): Selected
```

Additionally the NTFS Folder permissions have been fully unlocked for Everyone, Administrators, Users etc.

The aim is that any newly created files or folders are generally fully accessible, whether from the creator system/user or other Unix or Windows users.

I hope for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/608195/window-2008-inherit-permissions-from-parent-on-file-created-on-linux-nfs-share-c)

> The answer is in the registry:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Server for NFS\CurrentVersion\Mapping\KeepInheritance
>
> Change the value to a 1 and restart NFS.

Although I had to restart the server rather than any service.

There are a couple of other entries that look like they may help but are no longer used - AugmentDacl and InhibitDirectoryInheritance - together they look like they would achieve something similar to KeepInheritance

[Microsoft KB Archive/321049](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/321049)

> The following registry values are no longer valid in Windows Services
> for UNIX 2.3 and later:
>
> InhibitDirectoryInheritance
>
> AugmentDACL
>
> The functionality that these registry values controlled is now controlled by the  KeepInheritance registry value in Windows Services for UNIX 2.3.

That will keep the permissions that are being inherited however new files created by the NFS client will still have the extra privileges added (still trying to prevent that myself)